# any other option than eval in this javascript situation?

Tags: javascript, json, eval

i need to access a json file dynamically and am using the following code.  In this case, 'bpicsel' and 'temp' are variables.  The end result would be something like 'data[0].extit1'

```
var title="data["+bpicsel+"].extit"+temp;
$.getJSON('labs.json', function(data){
    title2 = eval(title);
    });
```

this works - but i am often told not to use eval - is there a better way?

Comment: `var title=data.bpicsel["extit" + temp];` inside of the getJSON call

Comment: There's always another way besides `eval`

Comment: @megawac thanks for the reply.  that doesn't seem to work - it creates the string i need but isn't evaluated in the function - it doesn't pull the entry from the json file that i need to access.  For example, it produces data[0].extit1 instead of giving me the value at that location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine

```
var title = data[bpicsel]['extit'+temp];
```

Now get your data as follows:

$.getJSON('labs.json', function(data){
    var title = data[bpicsel]['extit'+temp]; //no need for eval here
});

Comment: thanks for the reply, but same as the megawac answer, that doesn't seem to work - it creates the string i need but isn't evaluated in the function - it doesn't pull the entry from the json file that i need to access. For example, it produces data[0].extit1 instead of giving me the value at that location.

Comment: sorry I realized that you should use `title2 = data[bpicsel]['extit'+temp]`.  does that help?   This may help you as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name

Comment: thanks!  that worked.  for some reason, using var title = blahblah didn't work - maybe scope?

Comment: Yes, scope would cause that issue. Also the data variable isn't available until getJSON is done getting it, and passing into your anonymous function